# How to attach wire to a metal door?

Tags: wiring

[image: doorbell]

[image: lamp wire]

I want to run that lamp wire from the door cam down the door and to a power point. I'm struggling to work out how to attach the wire to the door in a way that's not too permanent but also will not easily come away.

Are there any standard "best ways" to do this? For example would silicone hold to the (metal) door frame and allow that brown from the lamp wire to slightly blend with the door?

Comment: do magnets stick to the door/frame? If not, then I would use my old renters trick of large globs of poster putty.

Comment: That must be the door itself on the left.  I see some rubber fittings.  How are those attached?  Also I hope that was not you that left those yellow scratches in the door.  Dad will be mad when he sees those.  It took him a long time to get the door that badass gray color.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Superglue work great for this. You can get the type that's a gel and run a stream of it down the door and then press the wire into it. The glue bond fast so you're not sitting there for an hour holding the wire in place. Running a single edge blade between the wire and door will remove the wire if needed.

What might work better is to install some wire mold like the type shown below from Menard's. It's got some self adhesive on the back to stick it to just about any surface and the you insert the wire inside. It does give a more professional appearance.

[image]